# Sending Mobile App Data to Country-specific GA4 Properties and Handling Pre-Language Selection Sessions

Tags: google-analytics, mobile-application, google-analytics-4

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am working on a mobile application that is going to be distributed across multiple countries. Each of these countries already has its own Google Analytics 4 (GA4) property set up, which they currently use for tracking their individual website data.

My requirement is to integrate the mobile app data with each country's GA4 property. The objective is to have the application's data flowing into the corresponding country's GA4 property based on the user's location or selection.

Could someone please guide me on the feasibility and implementation of this requirement? Specifically, I am looking for a way to direct the data to the respective country's GA4 property.

Furthermore, there will be user sessions created before the user has chosen their language or location in the app. I am not sure how to handle these sessions. How should the data from these sessions be managed or allocated in the GA4 properties?

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My requirement is to integrate the mobile app data with each country's GA4 property. The objective is to have the application's data flowing into the corresponding country's GA4 property based on the user's location or selection.